# Firefox problem with system extension permission prompt when using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-addon

My goal is to install Firefox extension from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/ when i run Python Selenium script. I need to test my web page with preinstalled extension (it can be any extension from the addons store).

My solution i am trying to perform is to install that extension through Selenium going to addons store and clicking on button "Add to Firefox":

```
    def install_addon(self):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.open('');")  # open new tab
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
        self.driver.get('https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension/')
        self.driver\
            .find_element_by_class_name("InstallButtonWrapper")\
            .find_element_by_class_name("AMInstallButton-button")\
            .click()
```

But the problem is a Firefox request for permissions. This is a confirmation prompt which i need to agree to continue installation:
[Screenshot of the firefox prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWe70.png)

I can't click to "Add" button through Selenium. Moreover i can't see HTML code of this popup.

So i see 3 possible variants to perform it but i do not know how.

1. How can i click on the button using Selenium?
2. How can i disable this popup? I do not see correct config in addons:config
3. Another variant to install extension from the store.

What variant can you recommend as best one and how to process it?

Thank you for help!